# Cross platform bookmark manager very many of items

Tags: document-management, bookmark

Few years ago I stopped using Bookmark manages in web browser due to several problems:

- It got messy very quickly
- it was slower to browse my bookmarks than browse the internet. I was never revisiting my bookmarks.
- The graphical user interface was not convenient for management of lot of bookmarks (like >10000)
- it was quite tedious to navigate nested sub-folder trees of bookmarks

What I need is bookmark manager similar to file manager.

- Full-screen window
- As many items per page as possible (small fonts). What I really hate about modern GUI that it is fashinable to waste screen space (make large borders, large fonts, large icons => small number of items per screen)
- easy browsing throw folder

Why I need so many bookmarks - mostly for **assembling personalized knowledge base of learning resources** and  e.g.:

- interesting pieces of code from various other-peoples github repos
- processing sketches form [OpenProcessing](https://www.openprocessing.org/) and shaders from [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/)
- wiki pages (from wikipedia, but also from more specialized wiki websites )
- answers from stackoverflow and othe stack exchange
- youtube and vimeo videos

Why to bookmark such things? Many of those webpages has own system to store "favorite" items ?

- Because I want to categorize my knowledge base by topic not by medium or or by webpage.
- Because I want some universal structure and user interface over all sources, not to adjust myself to specifics of each webpage
- because management of "favourites" is pretty crappy on some sites (e.g. youtube does not have sub-folders, and moving/deleting items is imposible or tedious)

Comment: I tried them all, and you simply cannot beat https://www.outertech.com/en/bookmark-manager

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a good notes program, not just a  bookmark manager.  Modern notes definitely include web content, or at least urls.  But then again you might object to them just as to modern ui?

Comment: Prokop, did you ever find a good one?

Comment: Mawg > saddly, I converged to most stupid solution: sending annotated gmails with links to myself and tagging them with topics. It is most platform independent, universal and fitting to old habits. When I tried anything else I always hit some wall.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [**TagSpaces**](https://www.tagspaces.org/) for this.

They store bookmarks in a form of `.url` or `.website` files, which may be tagged.

It has a free version, it is cross-platform and open source.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [pinboard.in](http://pinboard.in) for a ew years now. They don't have a treeview, but you can combine tags or create *bundles*.
A more modern presentation and interesting features are available on [tagpacker.com](http://tagpacker.com), however they don't yet have mobile apps.
Being a freelancer who regularly works on client's premises I can only consider cloud based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda a bit left field, but did you try [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/)?

Loads of scope for customisation, even if using primarily for bookmarks may not be the original focus of the project (it can do it).